# Which of Android Virtual Devices (AVD) is faster?

Tags: android, arm, intel, android-virtual-device

I've created and run an AVD with CPU/ABI: ARM(armeabi-v7a)

When AVD running, the emulator alerts:

[image]

Is `Intel x86 Atom System Image` AVD faster than `Intel x86 Atom_64` and `ARM EABI v7a`?

Comment: Yep `Intel x86 Atom System Image` is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Modern x86 CPUs support hardware virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization), so you can run an x86 Virtual Machine at near-native speed on x86 hardware (if you set up the appropriate stuff for your VM to use hardware virtualization, like Harkirat's answer mentions).  This applies to x86 and x86-64 VM images.

An ARM VM on x86 hardware has to be emulated, which is much slower.

---

> Is *Intel x86 Atom System Image* AVD faster than *Intel x86 Atom_64*?

No, I would expect that 64-bit and 32-bit Atom VMs run at nearly equivalent speeds.

> Is *Intel x86 Atom System Image* AVD faster than *ARM EABI v7a*?

Yes, and the factor of 10x sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use bluestacks app player instead of creating and using AVD's but if you want to stick to AVD then you can boost your emulator speed by installing HAXM from SDK manager.You can also make it fast by saving and loading snapshot of emulator state.Search google for

> saving snapshot of emulator state

Answer (score 0):

**Genymotion** is very fast and good，if you are a developer.

Comment: its okay no problem

Comment: Just a remark: it seems that personal (free) edition of Genymotion won't allow you to enable internet within the running VM.